# android studio firestore fetching array issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im creating a notepad with login and register which stores the notes to firestore and whenever i login it doesnt laod the notes but if i go back and login again it does

fetching array from firestore on create method

```
     userID= fauth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

   FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("notes")
            .document(userID).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    List<String> cloudnote = (List<String>) document.get("noteArray");

                    if (cloudnote==null) {
                        notes.add("Example note");
                    } else {
                        notes = new ArrayList<>(cloudnote);
                        System.out.println(logged_main.notes);
                    }
                }
            });
```

[firestore db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvcmT.jpg)

login

```
  fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(femail, fpassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();

                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), logged_main.class));
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error occured " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        login_btn.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: From the description it sounds that it has to do with handling async calls and order of calls in your code. Please share full login handling code.

Comment: @EmilGi i uploaded the login handling code

Comment: What do you mean by go back and login again'? Page reload? Or you logout and loging again? Also can you please share full code showing what gets called after what.